# vuex) how to Not all code paths error in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuex, typescript-typings

**Maybe I forgot the return type in this function. But I don`t know how to adapt it. First Keep my original function from migration to typescript
Plz share your answer :)**

```
const arrayPromise: Promise<string[]> = new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) => {
                // requset element : depAirportId, arrAirportId, depPlandTime // chose certain airline : &airlineId=AAR
                axios.get(url)
                    .then((res:any) => {
                        // ! Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)
                        const item = res.data.response.body.items.item
                        this.state.totalCount = res.data.response.body.totalCount
                        if(this.state.totalCount < 1)
                        return this.state.noTicket

                        this.state.depTime = res.data.response.body.items.item.forEach((obj:any) => {
                            /* 보간법을 이용하면 function 가능 (object에 간섭을 안하므로 가능) */
                            obj.depTime = `${obj.depPlandTime}`.slice(-4, -2)
                            /* Object.values : make every Object to Array */
                            return Object.values(obj)
                        })
                        this.state.depMin = res.data.response.body.items.item.forEach((obj:any) => {
                            obj.depMin = `${obj.depPlandTime}`.slice(-2)
                            return Object.values(obj)
                        })
                        this.state.arrTime = res.data.response.body.items.item.forEach((obj:any) => {
                            obj.arrTime = `${obj.arrPlandTime}`.slice(-4, -2)
                            return Object.values(obj)
                        })
                        this.state.arrMin = res.data.response.body.items.item.forEach((obj:any) => {
                            obj.arrMin = `${obj.arrPlandTime}`.slice(-2)
                            return Object.values(obj)
                        })
```

Comment: You need to `resolve(ret); return;` not `return ret;`. But if you just `res = await axios.get...` you can get rid of the `new Promise`, use return and don't throw into oblivion in case of an error.

Comment: Thx to answer it! I will try with your advice.

Comment: Sry. Can you advise more detail about it?

Comment: Added an "answer" doing much guesswork ... your code above does seem to miss something. I don't fill your this.state. objects but actually use the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if this code does make sense to you, as you where not giving info about the json that is returned, it was hard to figure out what you want actually. But I think it should help you.

Look at the comments describing the reason, I made changes ... your code does not make too much sense to me, especially the return value of string[]. I return the items you get from the call. If you need a string[], you should define what should be in that string array.

```
class YourClass {

state: any;

// use async functions in typescript
async arrayPromise(): Promise<any[]> { // i could not figure out what you want to return, so i return the items you parse in your function
    try {
        const result: any[] = [];

        // requset element : depAirportId, arrAirportId, depPlandTime // chose certain airline : &airlineId=AAR
        // ! url was undefined
        const url = 'https://';
        // call request and await the response (this is the way .this() is not the way, because it is just another callback hell)
        const res =  await axios.get(url);

        // ! do you realy need to modify this.state in this function?
        this.state.totalCount = res.data.totalCount;

        if (this.state.totalCount < 1) { // ! always use brackets (avoids fat-finger bugs like 'goto fail')
            // return this.state.noTicket; // ? ooh ... don't know what you want to return here, i guess an empty array.
            return result;
        }

        // ! don't use .forEach, because it does a callback on each element
        for (let obj of res.data.items) { // should iterate over youre Items ... 
            // parse some data and enrich the object
            obj.depTime = `${obj.depPlandTime}`.slice(-4, -2);
            obj.depMin = `${obj.depPlandTime}`.slice(-2);
            obj.arrTime = `${obj.arrPlandTime}`.slice(-4, -2);
            obj.arrMin = `${obj.arrPlandTime}`.slice(-2);

            // append the object to the result array
            result.push(obj.depTime);
        })
        // the additional forEach where superficial

        // Finally return the result.
        return result;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error occurred', error);
        throw error;
        // you can also `return [];` if you do not want to do error handling in the calling method
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Really appreciate it...! I`m gonna adapted.